# Should I remain silent during kedusha (if it's my minhag) in a kehila which doesn't?

Tags: minhag, kedusha-prayer, yekke

If one's personal minhag is to stay silent during the chazan's recitation of kedusha in the repetition of the 'Amidah (except for "kadosh…", "baruch…", and "yimloch…", which are recited in all minhagim) should one still keep this minhag when many or or most in the kehila recite all of the kedusha out loud?

For example, many recite the preface ("nekadeysh…" on weekdays and "na-'aritzecha…" on Shabas) and the passages between responses ("le-umasam…" and "uvdivrei…" on weekdays and "az bekol…", "mimkomcha…", and "[echad] hu Elokeynu…" on Shabas) which in German custom are only recited by the chazan. (A source for this is Rabbi Hamburger's *Shorshei Minhag Ashkenaz*, pg. 66.)

I figure remaining silent isn't so noticeable or disruptive to others so shouldn't be a problem - less so than reciting the entire kedusha out loud would be in a Ashkenaz shul where the kehila only said the responses.

Comment: Note remaining silent during most of Kedusha when not the leader isn't a Minhag but rather a Halakha which is unanimously agreed to by all Geonim and Rishonim, and the Shulchan Arukh/Rama.

Comment: I have several "Ashkenaz" siddurim (Koren, Artscroll, United Synagogue) that either suggest (either intentionally or by ambiguous instructions) or even directly instruct that the chazan's sections are also said by the kehila before the chazzan. Somewhere it seems to have become a norm if not a minhag!

Comment: Jakub, I remain silent during those portions of Kedushah, even though every schul in which I've davened does not do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Misha Berura may your question (SA 125:1:1).

> "ש"ע- אין הציבור אומרים עם הש"ץ "נקדש
>
> מ"ב- הטעם דניתקן שש"ץ יאמרנו בשביל הקהל ויהיה שלוחם וכשגם הצבור אומרים אותו איך יקרא הש"ץ שלוחם... כי על כ"א שבבהכ"נ החיוב לשתוק
>
> Shulchan Aruch- The congregation should not say "nekadesh" with the
>   chazzan.
>
> Mishna Berura - The reason is that the chazzan is saying
>   this on behalf of the congregation and he will be their "messenger,"
>   and if the congregation is also saying it, how can the chazzan be
>   called their messenger? ... It is the obligation of each individual to remain silent.

Seemingly regardless of your custom, you should never say "nekadesh" (or any other chazzan part).